# Huge mysqldump import

Tags: mysql

I have a 200+GB mysql dump file that I need to import into the local sql server running on my development machine. I attempted a naive dump restore using the 'mysql  < db_backup.sql' approach and managed to restore around 85% of the database before hitting a 'mysql server has gone away' error. This took in the region of 5 days.

I'd like to know if there's a way of comparing the partially restored DB to the dump file to understand which tables are still pending or if there's a significantly (at least 4x) quicker method to restore from a huge dump file.

Any advice would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: I think this question would be a better fit on http://dba.stackexchange.com try it there.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem, but with much less information (hundreads of MB, not GB). I have tried [BigDump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/), which splits inner content in queries, so that your restore operation does not time out (I think this is the cause of the error - 'mysql server has gone away').

However, if you can control how the dump is obtained, I would consider splitting of data to restore and optimizing the export. A way would be to split large table data into separate dumps.

Also, all inserts can be defined as extended inserts (one INSERT with multiple insert values), to save some space.